# Decomposing complex fermions into Majorana fermions (in 1D p-wave superconductor) and its relation to Majorana rep in (3+1)D QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, superconductivity, dirac-equation, majorana-fermions

I am following Topological Insulators and Topological Superconductors by B. A. Bernevig and T. L. Hughes. In ch. 16, the lattice model of 1D p-wave superconductor is solved by decomposing the complex fermion operators into Majorana fermions, as follow

\begin{equation}
c_{j} = \frac{1}{2}\left( \gamma_{2j-1}+ i \gamma_{2j}\right)
\end{equation}
where $j$ is the lattice site index. So we literally decompose a complex fermion degrees of freedom on a lattice site into two real degrees of freedom, as we require $\gamma_{j}^{\dagger}=\gamma_{j}$.

My question is that, based on my understanding of Majorana representation in (3+1)D QFT, we can switch between different representation, as long as the gamma matrices satisfy

\begin{equation}
\{\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu} \} = 2g^{\mu \nu}.
\end{equation}

And we can choose a representation such that all the gamma matrices are purely imaginary, which is the so-called Majorana representation. In this representation, the Dirac equation $(i \gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} -m)\psi = 0$ will be real. And this is helpful if we want to consider things like charge conjugation symmetry.

Now my question is, here I am looking at the 1D p-wave superconductor. But I don't quite know the connection between the decomposition of $c_{j}$ into $\gamma_{2j-1}$ and $\gamma_{2j}$ and things in (3+1)D QFT that the $\gamma$ matrices are all imaginary in the Majorana representation. I have some rough guess that in (3+1)D QFT the Dirac equation is real, and so this sort of corresponds to decomposing things into degrees of freedom that are purely real. But that is not very rigorous. Can someone demonstrate this in a rigorous way to help me connect things in 1D p-wave superconductor and what I have learned in (3+1)D QFT? And also demonstrate why we can always decompose a complex fermion into Majorana? Or maybe some suggestion on some examples that I can work out to understand the connection? Many thanks!